# jQuery Scrollable inside WordPress Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to use the following jQuery Scrollable plugin (which is displaying 5 photos per pane), from http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html on a Page in my WordPress theme but in a way that will allow the WP Admin user to go into this page and add/remove any images they want within this jQuery scrollable plugin by using the Page "Insert Media" capability in WordPress.

Is this possible? if so, how would you do this setup within a WP Page?

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar solution on a [portfolio site](http://andstones.ca) recently. It is relatively difficult to use the insert media capability only, I was able to do it using a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and then querying the posts that had a non-null custom field, and then using those images in the scrollable.

The scrollable on my page is a little more complex, as it uses rich text and images, but it is possible to use the WPquery to search for URL's in the custom fields, and then include just those images in the scrollable.

Thus there is a two step process. 1) Upload the images with the Insert Media, 2) Copy the URL into a Custom Field.

I wonder if it can be done automatically with the individual pages gallery....

:)

Comment: Hi @Kory - your portfolio site looks great and thanks for your response. FYI, I am fairly new to WP and unsure how to use the Custom Field side of things. Just wondering if you were able to provide a small example of using Custom Fields based on your response above. Thanks.

Comment: Each of the pages has a custom field that is a URL, then the slider is built inside a while have pages loop, pulling the custom field in as the source URL. You could also use the feature image...